# What is the current system requirements to be an Ethereum Validator node?

Tags: validators, the-merge

What kind of system do I need to run an Ethereum validator node at home? And do I need a static stable internet connection?

If requirements are too high, doesn't that mean I need to pay for a VPS? And does the rewards out weigh the cost of hosting?

Comment: you can find info on how to set up your own node or buy a fully loaded one here: https://ethereum.org/en/run-a-node/

Answer (score 2):

As of 9/2022:

Recommended hardware requirements to run a Full node:

- A fast CPU with 4+ cores
- 16 GB+ of RAM
- A fast SSD drive with at
  least 1 TB of space (storage capacity will grow over time)
- 25 MBit/s
  bandwidth

Recommended hardware requirements to run a Full Archive node:

- A fast CPU with 4+ cores
- 16 GB+ of RAM
- Storage will vary depending on the client software (ss of September 2022, archive mode on Geth takes ~12 TB and Erigon takes up ~2 TB).
- 25 MBit/s bandwidth

Source: https://www.quicknode.com/guides/infrastructure/ethereum-full-node-vs-archive-node

Comment: These specs are high. No one in their right mind even with 32eth can pay the hosting cost with these server specs. And I don't think your earnings in eth can pay the monthly cost. Is this true?